# How to show “Intra-package call graph” using “godoc”

Tags: call-graph, godoc

How can I show “Intra-package call graph” using `godoc` as described in [Intra-package call graph](https://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html#tmp_6) ?

I use this command

```golang
$ GO111MODULE=off godoc -http=:6060 -analysis=type,pointer
```

to start a local server and everything is fine. I just cannot find where the “Intra-package call graph” is.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It just takes too long to do "Pointer analysis", which is approximately 4.5 minutes on my laptop. The "Intra-package call graph" for hole package and every function appeared until "2021/03/16 15:04:28 Pointer analysis running..." had disappeared from my terminal.

And "-analysis=pointer" is just efficient.